# JavaScript Metro app background task error

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, background-process, winjs

I'm trying to create a background task for my JavaScript Metro app. I added these to the `default.js` file:

```
function RegisterBackgroundTask(taskEntryPoint, taskName, trigger, condition) {
    // Check for existing registrations of this background task.
    var taskRegistered = false;
    var background = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
    var iter = background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.allTasks.first();
    var hascur = iter.hasCurrent;

    while (hascur) {
        var cur = iter.current.value;
        if (cur.name === taskName) {
            taskRegistered = true;
            break;
        }
        hascur = iter.moveNext();
    }

    // If the task is already registered, return the registration object.
    if (taskRegistered == true) {
        return iter.current;
    }

    // Register the background task.
    var builder = new background.BackgroundTaskBuilder();

    builder.Name = taskName;
    builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
    builder.setTrigger(trigger);

    if (condition != null) {
        builder.addCondition(condition);
    }
    var task = builder.register();
    return task;
}

var trigger = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.SystemTrigger(Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.SystemTriggerType.timeZoneChange, false);

RegisterBackgroundTask("js\\bgtask.js", "test", trigger);
```

This is my `bgtask.js`:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var backgroundTaskInstance = Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIBackgroundTaskInstance.current;

    function doWork() {

        // Write JavaScript code here to do work in the background.
        console.log("task done");

        close();
    }

    doWork();
})();
```

This is my app manifest:

[image]

When I change the timezone, nothing happened. I checked the event log and there is an error:

> The background task with entry point  and name  failed to activate with error code 0x80040154.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
builder.Name = taskName;
builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
```

should be

```
builder.name = taskName;
builder.taskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
```